How to get python 2d numpy arrays of shape 2x2 from 4 1d arrays
Suppose I have 4 component arrays of size 6 (e.g., denoting 6 spatial locations in a grid):
Sxx = array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
Sxy = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
Then assume Syx = Sxy, and
Syy = array([1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1])
How do I retrieve the above arrays as 6 2×2 arrays, e.g., as below, in a "pythonic" way?

S = array([
      [[1.0, 0.1], [0.1, 1.1]], 
      [[2.0, 0.2], [0.2, 2.1]], 
      [[3.0, 0.3], [0.3, 3.1]], 
      ....
    ])

I could even work with 6 1-d 1x4 arrays as:

S = [
      [1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 1.1], 
      [2.0, 0.2, 0.2, 2.1], 
      [3.0, 0.3, 0.3, 3.1], 
      ....
    ]

Any ideas are much appreciated!

I stumbled upon the answer few moments after posting the question. What worked for me was:

nsamples = len(Sxx)
S3d = np.dstack((Sxx, Sxy, Syx, Syy)).reshape(nsamples, 2, 2)

Then printing S3d[0] for e.g., or otherwise, confirms what I expected. I also noted that this is easily extended to 3×3 shaped 2-d arrays
